# Error: Unable to resolve module ./Easing from node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I have migrated from `reanimated@1.9.0` and `react-native-gesture-handler@1.9.0` to

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
```

and when i open my app, the following error occurs:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./Easing from C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\RadioTangyStuff\radiotangy\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Easing(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
  * node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Easing\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
> 1 | import { Image, ScrollView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
  2 | import createAnimatedComponent from './createAnimatedComponent';
  3 | import {
  4 |   addWhitelistedNativeProps,
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\RadioTangyStuff\radiotangy\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:211:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\RadioTangyStuff\radiotangy\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\RadioTangyStuff\radiotangy\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:317:42)
    at resolve (C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\RadioTangyStuff\radiotangy\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:629:33)
    at C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\RadioTangyStuff\radiotangy\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:645:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\RadioTangyStuff\radiotangy\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:644:33)
    at C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\RadioTangyStuff\radiotangy\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:329:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\RadioTangyStuff\radiotangy\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:137:24)
```

I have searched in my project, I have not imported `Easing` anywhere (at least I think!)
I also seen the [migrating guide from Reanimated 1.x](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/migration)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: try to install the reanimated library `npm i react-native-reanimated`

Comment: If you are using `react-native-redash` update it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `react-native-redash` update it too

Answer (score 4):

this fix my problem:

```
yarn start  --reset-cache
```

Comment: the same answer here worked for me https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1896#issuecomment-823376711

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error on Android emulator with `react-native-reanimated@2.1.0`

As a temporary fix I've fixed the library to `react-native-reanimated@2.0.1` which seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Installing react-native-reanimated@next, ran npx pod-install and restarting my mac works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).